# Add text to 3D plot in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

So I'm making a 3d plot with plotly by using the x,y and z-axes. I'd like it to be an interactive plot so I can look at it from all angles, and so far so good because it is working. However, now I'm trying to insert text into the plot, which will serve to highlight some of the datapoints that are in there by adding a number above the marker itself.

I've been scouring the web to see how I should go about this and landed on add_annotations but I can't get it to work. My code is below. Does anyone know how I can do this? Ideally, I would like to give R the X,Y and Z coordinates for the text and just add as if they were markers.

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~age, y = ~height, z = ~weight,
        marker = list(symbol = "", line = list(color = 'rgb(0,0,0)', width = 2))) %>%
add_markers() %>%
add_annotations(list(y = 0.5, x = 0.5, text = "annotation"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data=mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, z = ~drat, mode="markers", type="scatter3d", 
        marker = list(symbol = "", line = list(color = 'rgb(0,0,0)', width = 2))) %>%
add_trace(x = mean(mtcars$mpg), y = mean(mtcars$hp), z=mean(mtcars$drat), 
          type = "scatter3d", mode="text", text = "annotation", inherit=FALSE)
```

[image]